# Круглые углы в Opera

Tags: opera, css

Почему в Opera не работает border-radius и как это исправить? Все остальные нормально отображают, даже ie.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"/>
<title>Поиск</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/notes.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="yandexform" onclick="return {
'bg': '#C7DAFE', 
'language': 'ru',
'encoding': '', 
'suggest': false, 
'tld': 'ru', 
'site_suggest': false,
'webopt': false,
'fontsize': 12, 
'arrow': false, 
'fg': '#000000', 
'logo': 'rb',
'websearch': false,
'type': 3}">
<form action="http://yandex.ru/sitesearch" method="get" target="_blank">
<input id="searchid" type="hidden" name="searchid" value="1856960"/><input id="text" name="text"/><input id="search" type="submit" value="Найти"/>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/yandexsearch.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
form {
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```

}

```
#text {
width: 68%;
-moz-border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
border-color: #3571b6;
```

}

```
#search {
width: 29%;
-moz-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
color: #fefefe;
background-color: #1a385b;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3571b6), to(#1a385b));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3571b6, #1a385b);
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3571b6, #1a385b);
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3571b6, #1a385b);
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #3571b6, #1a385b);
background-image:         linear-gradient(top, #3571b6, #1a385b);
border-color: #3571b6;
```

}

```
#search:hover {
cursor: pointer;
```

}

Comment: Можно пример? В Opera уже давно работает вроде.

Answer (score 2):

Опера поддерживает атрибут border-radius только начиная с версии 10.5

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй -o-border-radius: 5px;

Comment: Нет, не помогло.

Comment: Обновите кэш (кнопка F5). Опера часто не обновляет кэш, даже при нажатии на F5. Если не F5, То напиши ссылку на файл стилей так: ../path/style.css?v=1.1

Comment: Ну он применяет другие же стили, кроме этого. Не работает. А про ссылку не понял. Даже градиент работает. Просто у меня элемент который надо закруглить, это input. Может из-за этого?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="core/home/css/style.css?v=1.1" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
Т.е. добавить ?v=1.1 Это дает браузеру знать, что стоит подгрузить новую версию стилей. Но дело, говорите, не в этом..
Дайте ссылку на сайт, пожалуйста

Comment: тогда пример в студию

Comment: Скорее всего у вас просто старая опера.
P.S. Для тега form border-radius, Насколько я знаю, задавать не нужно

Answer (score -1):

Делайте сайты по стандарту XHTML 1.0.
Заточка сайта под конкретный браузер - это колхоз в обход стандартов с риском получить от нормального браузера в рыло (страница сделана не по стандарту => её невозможно правильно отобразить => обратитесь к разработчикам сайта, чтобы узнать какой браузер по их мнению вы должны использовать => просмотр на стандартном браузере по стандарту невозможен).

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">
        <head>
                <title>Стандартный сайт</title>
        </head>
         <body>
                <h1>Соблюдение стандарта гарантирует одинаковое стандартное отображение в любом стандартном браузере</h1>
        </body>
</html>

Если страницы сайта не проходят валидацию на http://validator.w3.org/, то пользователи могут увидеть вашу криворукость.

Comment: Стандарт для каскадных таблиц стилей (CSS)
http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/

Поддерживаемые стандартом свойства "border":
'border-top-width', 'border-right-width', 'border-bottom-width', 'border-left-width', and 'border-width' 

'border-top-color', 'border-right-color', 'border-bottom-color', 'border-left-color', and 'border-color' 

'border-top-style', 'border-right-style', 'border-bottom-style', 'border-left-style', and 'border-style' 

'border-top', 'border-bottom', 'border-right', 'border-left', and 'border'

Никакого border-radius в стандарте CSS нет и, возможно, не будет!